# Excel VBA Adding Parentheses around Column Name in formulas

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, formula

I have this very basic code in VBA:

```
Activecell..Formula2 = "=XLOOKUP(RC[-100],'[" & wbState.Name & "]" & wsState.Name & "'!B:B,'[" & wbState.Name & "]" & wsState.Name & "'!A:A)")
```

and it is giving me a weird result. The formula keeps showing up in excel like this:

```
=XLOOKUP(D3,[States.xlsx]Sheet1!B:(B),[States.xlsx]Sheet1!A:(A))
```

I have done this hundreds of times in the past but I haven't done it in a very long time.  Now, when I try to do this, it is putting Parenthesis around the second half of a column range.  In the formula above, as an example B:(B) and A:(A)

What changed in excel to do this? Is it a bug or am I missing something stupid.  I have also tried this in VB.net and I get the same result.

Comment: You're mixing R1C1 (`RC[-100]`) and A1 (`B:B`, `A:A`) notation.

Comment: Note that you can use `Formula2R1C1`.  (The `Formula2*` variants weren't a thing when the linked Q&A was written)